# How to get a permanent token of a single raw file of a private github repo that will lasts for several days

Tags: github

How to get  a permanent token of a  single raw file of a private github repo that will lasts for several days.

I have a shell-script file in a private repo of github & after clicking raw button i get url with which i can download that file using 'wget'. Link is something like below.
Now the raw token=AKNX3RPGGGQA5KGXL5AQYUS7DBW4I  remains valid only for 30secs or 1 minute.

i wanna get or generate a token for this raw file in my private repo that will lasts for several days, as this link will be provided to my clients to run few pre-defined tasks in the script(we don't wanna give my clients my github personal access token).

How i can achieve this scenario.
Quick response will be appreciated.
Thanks

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repoName/master/hello.sh?token=AKNX3RPGGGQA5KGXL5AQYUS7DBW4I

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repoName/master/hello.sh?token=AKNX3RPGGGQA5KGXL5AQYUS7DBW4I -O hello.sh
```